# What were the Grand Prix rankings in Yuri on Ice?

Tags: yuri-on-ice

Yuri on Ice covers one entire Grand Prix series, but the viewers only actually watch the three parts (the Cup of China, the Rostelecom Cup, and the Grand Prix Final) that Yuuri competes in. However, different characters compete in all of the different competitions in it. I was wondering, what are the rankings for each of the Grand Prix competitions in the competitive season that the show (thus far) covers?